# How to execute multiple queries in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert an account info for example cash in table `TBL_Account` and at the same time I want to create a table with the same account name Cash.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AccountSaveAccount]
   @AccountId int,
   @AccountName nvarchar(Max),
   @PortalId int,
   @CultureCode nvarchar(100),
   @UserModuleId int,
   @AddedBy nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @SQLInsertString NVARCHAR(MAX)

   if(@AccountId = 0)
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO dbo.AccountTable
    (
    AccountId,
    AccountName,
    PortalId,
    CultureCode,
    UserModuleId,
    AddedBy,
    AddedOn,
    UpdatedBy,
    UpdatedOn,
    IsDeleted
    )
    VALUES
    (
    @AccountId,
    @AccountName,
    @PortalId,
    @CultureCode,
    @UserModuleId,
    @AddedBy,
    GETDATE(),
    @AddedBy,
    GETDATE(),
    0
    );

    END

    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].['+@AccountName+'](
    [AccountCatId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountCatName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [InsertedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Particulars] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ParticularsBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ParticularsTo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Dr] [int] NULL,
    [Cr] [int] NULL,
    [DebitedAccountId] [int] NULL,
    [CreditedAccountId] [int] NULL,
    [DebitAmount] [float] NULL,
    [CreditAmount] [float] NULL,
    [AddedBy] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [AddedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [UpdatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    [DeletedBy] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DeletedOn] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_'+ @AccountName +'] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AccountCatId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]'

EXEC (@SQLString)

    END
```

But it only creates table but does not insert into the table.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not really a good idea to create tables dynamically like that. It's not the way SQL is intended to work. I don't see why your insert wouldn't be working though, unless you're not passing `0` for `@AccountId` like your `if` is checking for?

Comment: Your problem is with your If statement where `@AccountId = 0`? Where is the value being passed for the AccountId?

Comment: I agree with Blorgbeard - this looks like a horrifically bad idea. Why would you want to create a whole new table for each account? As to your question - my guess is that the `@AccountId` you're passing is `NULL`, which does not `= 0`.

Comment: I have passed @AccountId = 0.Creating a dynamic Table is important as user must create its own category.previously i have placed the create table inside the if then also it only executes to create the table but it doesnot insert the name inside the dbo.AccountTable.What can be a better way for creating dynamic table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert nvarchar to varchar in create query

like this

```
SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].['+convert(varchar(200),@AccountName)+'](
```

or

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_'+ convert(varchar(200),@AccountName) +'] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: The dynamic table created sucessfully but my problem is that the insert query is not working tho i am passing @AccountId= 0

Comment: Check you Accountid coulmn design specification. IF it is primary key then not inserted o value. If any foreign key then not inserted o value.

Comment: What a silly mistake i have made.I made  AccountId as primary key and i was inserting AccountId.Thank you @Mukesh